# Change variable in main form (Winform c#)

Tags: c#, forms, variables

I'm new to Visual studio and I created a Project with a Form1 and another Form called Form2. Form2 will be opened by this code:

`Form2 form = new Form2();
 form.Show();`

When i click a Button in Form2 I want to change a variable in my Form1. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Form1 is single instance, you can declare a variable as public static in Form1 code

```
public static int MyVariable;
```

then you can access it within Form2 like below:

```
Form1.MyVariable = 5;
```

Comment: Not sure why someone has -1 this answer. +1 as this is completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

In `Form2` ctor:

```
public Form2(Form1 fm)
{
    this.Fm = fm;
}
```

And call it in `Form1`, like this:

```
Form2 form = new Form2(this);
form.Show();
```

This is useful if Form1 is not a single instance.

Comment: You failed to mention what "Fm" is, and that the variables that the user wants to modify cannot be set to private. And another option is to use static variables.

Comment: `Fm` is form. Thought it was inferred by this line `Form1 fm`, which tells us we have a `Form1` called `fm` which is an abbreviation of the same convention btn and txt follow. So, `this.Fm` is the same name as `fm` so it can be assumed its a `Form1`, considering we are passing it that type. Also, even with static variables, the user is still limited to the public ones.

Comment: Didn't mean what it is, but where you declare it. As this stands, you will get a compiler error saying that Fm doesn't exist.

Comment: I know, I left that up to OP. I trust he's smart enough to know he needs to declare the variable. I'm only here to write the parts he doesn't know.

Comment: Question was about how to access a variable in another class. Please add some code and mentoin *public* accessor. Current answer is nothing to do with variable access, but it is a better practice since static is dangerous to newbies.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static variable in `Form1`, the variable that you need to change. Let it be `int x` for example

```
public static int x= 0;
```

The line up there must be defined in `Form1`
Then inside the function in `Form2` for the button click:

```
Form1.x = //value;
```

Comment: How is this different to @Ramazan Binarbasi's answer?

Comment: Oh it's not... I just saw his comment now.